# Finite sigma-algebra; integrating a non-simple function.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

To help me learn measure theory I have come up with a finite example to work with. We take the set $X=[0,1]$ and the three sets $A_1=[0,0.2]$, $A_2=[0.7,1]$ and $A_3=(0.2,0.7)$ (the idea for this come from  [here](http://sas.uwaterloo.ca/~dlmcleis/s901/chapt2.pdf)). The collection of subsets:
$$\{\emptyset, A_1,A_2,A_3,A_1\cup A_2, A_1\cup A_3, A_2 \cup A_3, \Omega\}$$ then forms a sigma-algebra. On which I have defined the measure (analogous to the Lebesgue measure), $\mu$ as:
$$\mu(A_i=[a,b])=b-a,\; \mu(A_i \cup A_j)=\mu(A_i)+\mu(A_j)$$
(where $[a,b]$ may be open or closed). Then using this measure we can perform integration of simple functions e.g.:
$$f=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{for} \; 0\le x \le 0.2 \\ 0 & \text{for}\; 0.2\lt x\lt 0.7\\ 3& \text{for}\; 0.7\le x\le 1\end{cases}=1\chi_{A_1}+3\chi_{A_2}$$
where $\chi_{A_i}$ represents the characteristic function of $A_i$. This means that the integral of $f$ is:
$$\int fd\mu=1\mu(A_1)+3\mu(A_2)=1\times(0.2-0)+3\times(1-0.7)=1.1$$
I am wanting to come up with an analogous example for the integration of a non-simple function. This is defined (see [here](http://www.maths.manchester.ac.uk/~cwalkden/ergodic-theory/lecture09.pdf)) using the fact that if $f$ is measurable then there exists a sequence of simple functions $f_n$ such that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x)$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$ and we have:
$$\int fd\mu=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int f_nd\mu$$
Using this sigma-algebra and this measure please could someone help me come up with an example of this? I would like to see both how $f_n(x)\rightarrow f(x)$, how we find $f_n$ and how we use this to find the intergral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to construct a non-simple measurable function using a finite $\sigma$-algebra, because the preimage of every measurable set in $\mathbb{R}$ is going to need to be in your $\sigma$-algebra for $f$ to be measurable. Namely, if $f(A_i)$ contains two distinct points $y_1$ and $y_2$, then $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})\cap A_i\neq \emptyset$ and $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})\cap A_i\neq \emptyset$, but $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})\cap f^{-1}(\{y_2\}) = \emptyset$, so $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})\cap A_i\neq A_i$ and $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})\cap A_i\neq A_i$. This implies that $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})$ and $f^{-1}(\{y_2\})$ are not in your $\sigma$-algebra. Thus, we can let $y_i = f(x)$ for all $x\in A_i$, and we will have that $f$ is a simple function taking at most three possible values ($n$ possible values for a $\sigma$-algebra generated by $n$ disjoint sets).

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you by any chance know any easy examples for any infinite $\sigma$-algebras?

Comment: I believe that my initial introduction to $\sigma$-algebras and integration used the Lebesgue $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^n$. You might consider starting there.